# How to use decorators in react server side rendered app?

Tags: reactjs, decorator, server-side-rendering, babel-loader

I have an app(with SSR) running. Recently I tried adding `decorator` support. I have done the configuration and app runs perfectly fine when it runs in the browser (Because code running in browser is babel-transpiled).

However code(Component containing decorator) breaks when it is rendered on server-side - May be because, the code which is getting executed is not transpiled and node is not able to understand `@` symbol.

It it throwing below error

```
   (node:1932) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: 
src/components/common/InputBox/InputBox.js: Unexpected token (8:0)

        import './InputBox.scss';
           7 |
        >  8 | @autobind
             | ^
           9 | class InputBox extends Component {
          10 |     constructor(props) {
          11 |         super(props);
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: *the code which is getting executed is not transpiled and node is not able to understand @ symbol.* - it really isn't. Use Babel.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you haven't set up support for decorators. That means that your code is not transformed, and `node` (which runs your server script) don't know how to process `@foo` kind of code. Decorators at 2nd stage (see https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/ ) and not part of the language. If you use babel to transform your code, add corresponding plugin (`@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators`).

Comment: Is there an example of such configuration?

Comment: @ImamudinNaseem I need more details about how you compile your scripts. Do you use babel? If so - could you share your babel config please? You can add it by updating your initial post.